# Can't load static image in django when using a loop

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I cant get an image to load in django when i use a for loop, the image will load if i specify the path for each file.

Works:

when I try to use a loop it won't load the images.

view.py:

```
  operators = []
   directory = 
      os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR)
      ,'static'),'images'),'operators')
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
      if file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpg"):
        operators.append(file)
```

then i try to return image using context.

html file:

```
  {% if operators %}
      There are {{ operators|length }} records:
      {% for operator in operators %}
        <div class="media">
          <img src="{{operator}}" class="align-self-center mr-3" alt="...">
        </div>
        {{operator}}
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      There are no records in the system
    {% endif %}
```

It would be amazing if someone had an idea on how to fix my code.

settings.py:

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 # Pointing django to the static file location. 
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
```

Comment: how many images are there in operators ?

Comment: only 2 images in the folder

Comment: Well then don't use that views looping logic (it won't work as when you deploy your application your static directory will get changed and also it has security issues ). Simply pass `['images/operators/image1.jpeg','images/operators/image2.png']` and then in template ` simply loop that array and display it using `<img src="{% static '{{ operatorimg_url }}' %}">`.

Comment: But it eventually will have 30+ photos on that folder, would this be the only way?

Comment: Statistic files are served as files which are not going to change for ex some background image, css files, js files etc. If you have dynamic files such as profile images which need to be updated amd added dynamically then treat it as media files.

Comment: You will add more operators in future right ?

Comment: yeah i will be, sorry only learning this framework, not sure how to get the images to show without using static files, not sure how to present it as a media object

Comment: Refer [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/data-flair.training/blogs/django-static-files-handling/amp/) for static files. After learning that go for [media](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/08/28/advanced-django-file-handling/) files. Don't worry you can learn it, don't hesitate to ask questions it will improve your programming skills. : )

Comment: image still not coming out, i have defined the MEDIA_URL = '/images/' and
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images'),  then added the pictures to the folder images/operators/.....on my template i have done {{ TakeSnap.url }}....because TakeSnap is now a field in my model.....not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: If i go to the URL i can see the file and all just cant get them showing when i try to loop.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may vary depending on which version of Django you're using.

For Django 3.0, the following should work

```
# settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'static',
]
```

Then inside templates-

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static '{{ operator.url }}' %}">
```

I'm guessing the images may appear instead with the following-

```
<img src="{{ operator.url }}">
```